# Meaning of "tumbleweed coifs"

Tags: word-meaning, british-english

I am currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/british-prime-minister-boris-johnson-094913963.html), and there was a word,

> This isn’t just another hackneyed reference to Johnson’s surface similarities to Donald Trump, which include urine-colored **tumbleweed coifs,** the elevation of pathological mendacity to a political art form, and, excepting Johnson’s higher erudition (he regularly spouts gobbets of ancient Greek), the impressive willingness to speak without coherence or elementary knowledge about the things that supposedly matter most to either man.

What is exactly the "tumbleweed coifs"? I googled and looked up, but only what I got is very few resources, kindly help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You won't find "Tumbleweed coifs" in a dictionary because it is a creative combination invented by Michael Weiss who wrote the article you refer to.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coif), "coif" is short for "coiffure" which comes from French and means "hairstyle".

Since pictures are worth a thousand words apiece, this is a picture (from Wikipedia) of a tumbleweed at a gas station:

[image: tumbleweed]

And this is a picture from the Spectator blog, showing actual photos, side-by-side, of Johnson's and Trump's hair, respectively:

[image: from https://blogs.spectator.co.uk/2016/02/donald-trumps-secret-weapon-boris-style-hair/]

The author must have felt a new term was necessary to fully convey his meaning.

Comment: Comedians and commentators are constantly coming up with metaphors to describe people like Trump and Johnson. Trump is usually ridiculed for his fake tan, but his toupee gets plenty of jokes as well.